# Accessing Data from Custom Object in a Repeated List

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a class defined in dart that looks like this:

```dart
class Page extends Object with Serializable {
  String name;

  Page(this.name);

  String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

and a custom polymer element structured like this:

```dart
<polymer-element name="sidebar-list">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{page in pages | enumerate}}">
        <li>{{page.value}}</li> // what do I call here to get the name of the page?
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

and a method that defines the polymer object:

```dart
@CustomTag('sidebar-list')
class SidebarList extends PolymerElement {
  final List<Page> pages = <Page>[new Page('Page 1'), new Page('Page 2'), new Page('Page 3')];

  SidebarList.created() : super.created();
}
```

`Pages` is a List of `Page` defined in the custom polymer.

My question is this: how do I reference a method inside of a class from a polymer element placeholder? I tried all the logical things like `{{page.value.toString()}}` and `{{page.value.name}}` and `{{page.name}}` but nothing works.

Interestingly, if the List is of Strings and not pages, `{{page.value}}` returns a String as expected.

Is this even possible?

Thank you so much for you help! I can offer any clarification if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `| enumerate` you should use

```
<li>{{page.value.name}}</li>
```

without `| enumerate`

```
<li>{{page.name}}</li>
```

If you not initialize the field like

```dart
final List<Page> pages = <Page>[new Page('Page 1'), new Page('Page 2'), new Page('Page 3')];
```

you need to add `@observable` so Polymer recognizes when a new value was assigned.

```dart
@observable
final List<Page> pages;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your change works perfectly with the @observable tag! I appreciate the help.